# grouping datatable based on time from one column and get average of other columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

trying to group the data based on time span of 1 hour and getting the average of another column in a data table. The data table may contain 2 or more value columns with 1 datetime coulmn. 
example:
    
    `time                result1    result2
    1/1/2013 1:38:03 AM 2.3         3.2
    1/1/2013 1:52:23 AM 2.5         4.2
    1/1/2013 1:54:43 AM 4.1         1.9
    1/1/2013 1:57:00 AM 3.3         5.1
    1/1/2013 2:11:28 AM 3.2         0
    1/1/2013 2:43:58 AM 3.3         8.4
    1/1/2013 2:46:20 AM 4.3         3.3
    1/1/2013 4:50:47 AM 3.9         2.3
    1/1/2013 6:48:57 AM 3.3         4.3`

expected: Hourly grouping(date will be same) and average of results

```
time                result1                  result2
1/1/2013 1:38:03 AM (2.3+2.5+4.1+3.3)/4      (3.2+4.2+1.9+5.1)/4
1/1/2013 2:11:28 AM (3.2+3.3+4.3)/3          (0+8.4+3.3)/3
1/1/2013 4:50:47 AM 3.9/1                    2.3/1
1/1/2013 6:48:57 AM 3.3/1                    4.3/1
```

Can we use Linq query on datatable to get this result? Tried some of the samples from google nothing worked for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider how you would do it if you did it in a regular SQL query.  You'd want to group by the date and hour and aggregate the appropriate fields.

```
select min([time]) as [time], avg([result1]) as [result1], avg([result2]) as [result2]
from some_table
group by convert(date, [time]), datepart(hour, [time])
order by [time]
```

Then do the same using linq:

```
from t in db.SomeTable
orderby t.Time
group t by new { t.Time.Date, t.Time.Hour } into g
select new
{
    Time = g.Min(t => t.Time),
    Result1 = g.Average(t => t.Result1),
    Result2 = g.Average(t => t.Result2),
}
```